# Cannot configure Spring Security to load .loginPage("/login") only the default page works or it sends to /templates/index.html

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am trying to setup a custom login page for `Spring Security` with `Spring Boot` and `ReactJS`.  I have now decided to get this working without `ReactJS` and just use the Thymeleaf templates for the login page.

If I do not provide the `loginPage()` to `formLogin()` in my `Spring` `SecurityConfiguration` I can log in via the default login screen and authentication works within the application.

The problem comes when I try to setup a custom login page within `SecurityConfiguration` I can not get it to load the login correctly when I go to the app.

```
 .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
```

When I go to the default address on port 8081 (configured via application.properties):

```
http://localhost:8081/
```

I will be sent to the `/templates/index.html` not `login.html` when I `view source`?

I tested this by adding in the login requirements for `Spring Security` within index.html

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
      <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
      <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
  </form>
```

This will load up the fields to login but I dont want to have it load the index I want it to load the login.  My question is WHY is it sending me to index.html and not login.html?

**QUESTION**

1. What am I missing in the setup to allow to go to login.html and not index.html?

Does it have to do with the setup for the matchers for permitAll()?

```
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/built/**", "/main.css").permitAll()
```

Thank you

**Code below**

Spring SecurityConfiguration`

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private SpringDataJpaUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoder.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/built/**", "/main.css").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
      .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/#/login") // for reactjs 
                //.loginPage("/login") // for login.html
        .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
        .and()
      .httpBasic()
        .and()
      .csrf().disable()  // TODO enable for production
      .logout()
              .invalidateHttpSession(true)
              .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
  }

}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>M Cellblock</title>
    <!-- cerulean style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/react-date-picker.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react"></div>

    <script src="built/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Second try**

`antMatchers("")` rules are applied in order given, so if you first permitted acces to `"/"` to `all` authentication is not required and probably that's why `index` page is loaded. Try removing `"/"` from `permitAll` list. 
Requesting anything other than stated there sholud require authentication and redirect to login page.

That's how it's done in configuration I've posted.

**First try**

In my Vaadin app adding:

```
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login/"))
```

to HttpSecurity configuration does the work (but I also have servlet mapped to `/login` ).

Here is my full conf:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/**", "/VAADIN/**", "/PUSH/**",
                    "/UIDL/**", "/login", "/login/**", "/register",
                    "/environment").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login/"))
                .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
}
```

Comment: Still with these changes it goes to index.html and not loading the login.html page under /templates

Comment: It turns out it was since I did not have the controller setup for /login to go to the login template.  Thank you for your help though.